# How to get rows whose nth column contains mth column

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, csv

I have a CSV file contains domains and webmails, like this:

```
site1.com,mail.site1.com
site2.com,testmail.com
site3.com,mx.site3.com
site4.com,smtp.site4.com
site5.com,foomail.com
site6.com,barmail.com
site7.com,webmail.site7.com
site8.com,01mx.site8.com
site9.com,foobarmail.com
site10.com,mx-smtp222.site10.com
```

I want to get rows where the webmails column contains the domains column of the same row.  For the example above, the output should be:

```
site1.com,mail.site1.com
site3.com,mx.site3.com
site4.com,smtp.site4.com
site7.com,webmail.site7.com
site8.com,01mx.site8.com
site10.com,mx-smtp222.site10.com
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F, '$2 ~ $1"$"' file.csv
```

- `-F,` sets the field separator as `,`
- `$2 ~ $1"$"` tests if the second field ends with the first field; if so, print the record (default action)

---

With `grep`, `grep` by default print only matched lines:

```
grep -E '^([^,]+),.*\1$' file.csv
```

---

With `sed`, printing lines matching the condition:

```
sed -nE '/^([^,]+),.*\1$/ p' file.csv
```

**Example**:

```
% cat file.txt
site1.com,mail.site1.com
site2.com,testmail.com
site3.com,mx.site3.com
site4.com,smtp.site4.com
site5.com,foomail.com
site6.com,barmail.com
site7.com,webmail.site7.com
site8.com,01mx.site8.com
site9.com,foobarmail.com
site10.com,mx-smtp222.site10.com

% awk -F, '$2 ~ $1"$"' file.txt
site1.com,mail.site1.com
site3.com,mx.site3.com
site4.com,smtp.site4.com
site7.com,webmail.site7.com
site8.com,01mx.site8.com
site10.com,mx-smtp222.site10.com

% grep -E '^([^,]+),.*\1$' file.txt
site1.com,mail.site1.com
site3.com,mx.site3.com
site4.com,smtp.site4.com
site7.com,webmail.site7.com
site8.com,01mx.site8.com
site10.com,mx-smtp222.site10.com


% sed -nE '/^([^,]+),.*\1$/ p' file.txt 
site1.com,mail.site1.com
site3.com,mx.site3.com
site4.com,smtp.site4.com
site7.com,webmail.site7.com
site8.com,01mx.site8.com
site10.com,mx-smtp222.site10.com
```